# How can I SERDE to build generic file ingestion into Hive?

Tags: hive, hive-serde

I need to build generic file ingestion into Hive. The files are very large (2GB+), can be fixed or comma-separated, ASCII or EBCDIC files. After trying various techniques using Talend, I am looking into SERDE. If I ingest the files as-is and use a schema file (containing ordinal position, column name, type, length), can I create a custom SERDE to de-serialize any input file into hive rows? How performant would it be?

Answer (score 0):

Since asking this question, I found that I could use a [COBOL custom SERDE](https://rbheemana.github.io/Cobol-to-Hive/serde.html).
I am also looking at regex SERDE for positional files.